# Save/Load editable Fall tree in javafx

Tags: javafx

i have a editable fall tree which i want to save and load here is my code

```
 public class Muddassir extends Application 
    {

        private BorderPane root;
        TreeView<String> tree;
        TreeItem<String> module,unite,translateA ,translateB,rotate;
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
        {    
            root = new BorderPane();        
            root.setLeft(getLeftHBox());
            root.setTop(getTop());

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 900, 500);        
            primaryStage.setTitle("BorderPane");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();    
        }

        private VBox getLeftHBox()
        {
            TreeItem<String> rootnode = new TreeItem<String>("Library");
            rootnode.setExpanded(true);
            module = makeBranch("module",rootnode);
            makeBranch("Parameter X",module);
            unite = makeBranch("unite",module);
            makeBranch("Parameter uX",unite);
            translateA = makeBranch("translateA",unite);
            makeBranch("Parameter taX",translateA);
            translateB = makeBranch("translateB",unite);
            makeBranch("Parameter tbX",translateB);
            rotate = makeBranch("rotate",translateB);
            makeBranch("Parameter RX",rotate);
            tree= new TreeView<>(rootnode);
            tree.setEditable(true);
            tree.setCellFactory(TextFieldTreeCell.forTreeView());



            VBox vbox =new VBox(10);
            vbox.setPadding(new Insets(5));
            Text text= new Text("Fall tree");
            text.setFont(Font.font("I", FontWeight.BOLD,16)); 
            vbox.getChildren().addAll(text,tree);
            return vbox;
        }

        private TreeItem<String> makeBranch(String title, TreeItem<String> parent) {
            TreeItem<String>item = new TreeItem<>(title);
            item.setExpanded(true);
            parent.getChildren().add(item);
            return item;

        }       

         private Parent getTop() {
             TextField fieldName = new TextField();
              Button btSave = new Button("Save");
               btSave.setOnAction(event -> {
                   SaveData data = new SaveData();
                  // data.name = ((TreeView<String>) tree).getText();
                   data.name = fieldName.getText();
                   try {
                     Function.save(data, "Javafx.save");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                });


               Button btLoad = new Button("Load");
                btLoad.setOnAction(event -> {
                   try {
                      SaveData data = (SaveData) Function.load("Javafx.save");      
                     //((TreeItems<String>)tree).setText(data.name);
                     fieldName.setText(data.name);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              });

                HBox hb= new HBox(5,fieldName,btSave,btLoad);
                hb.setPadding(new Insets(5));
            return hb;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Application.launch(args);
        }
    }
```

And Function class is

```
 import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;

    public class Function {
           public static void save(Serializable data, String fileName) throws Exception {
                try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(fileName)))) {
                    oos.writeObject(data);
                }
            }
            public static Object load(String fileName) throws Exception {
                try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(fileName)))) {
                    return ois.readObject();
                }
            }
        }
```

And SaveData Class is

```
 import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;

    public class SaveData implements java.io.Serializable{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public String name;

    }
```

I wanted to edit the Tree and make changes, save that changes and after next execution, i should have that changed result. Since i don't know much about database so i came up with this method to save changes in a file and load that file.

Problem is that i can save and load text in textfield but i cannot save and load changes in tree.

I want to save changes in tree and load these changes on my next execution. I tried but failed.

Thank you.

Comment: This is Old post and it is solved. so Please Don't provide Answer. Thank you